# Application won't install after release build signed

Tags: android

The app works fine in debug. But when I build it in release mode, and sign it, it will not install on any devices unless they are configured to allow apps from unknown sources i.e. the phone says "For security, your phone is set to block installation of applications not obtained from Android Market"

The app will not install from dropbox, or the gmail app.

It won't install on a Galaxy Nexus, a Samsung Galaxy S II, a Nexus One, amongst others.

As far as I can see the signing process works fine - there are no errors.

I've tried signing with a key from another app, and that fails too, when that key works fine for another app. This suggests the key is not the problem.

The APK is definitely a release build.

So what are the checks Android performs before it allows a signed, release app to be installed? How does it know it's not from a trusted source?

Comment: It is exactly as you cite: "For security, your phone is set to block installation of applications not obtained from Android Market", I.E, the app has to be downloaded from Android Market for the error to disappear, and nowhere else (unless the user has enabled "allow non-market apps" as stated in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to enable the devices to "allow non-market apps" to be installed else it will complain.

You will find this somewhere in Settings->Development.

Comment: I'm aware this setting will get rid of the error, but it's a release build, designed to go into the Market, but we can't release it until we ensure users DON'T have to use this option.

Comment: Well, It works that way. Precisely, "Non-market apps" means, apps that are not downloaded from the android market.

Comment: Apologies, I had it in my head that it was possible to install signed apps destined for the Market with this setting off. Now you mention it that clearly makes no sense. I edited your answer so I could up-vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before.

[Try the steps listed here](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/)

Also, go to settings, then Applications. Theres a button to allow it at the top of that screen.

Answer (score 0):

Find option Unknown Source and make it enable.
Some have this option in setting --> Application
Some have this option in setting --> Security